# jenkins pipeline - how to build a docker image in a declarative pipeline steps use powershell command

Tags: powershell, docker, jenkins-pipeline

I'm trying to build a asp.net docker image by jenkins declarative pipeline,the flow is running on a jenkins slave manchine windows server2019 ,so it need to use powershell to run docker command,the powershell version is 5.1,when I write docker build parameter exactlt in command,it running success,
the command is:

```
 stage('Build Container') {
            steps {
              echo "Build Container ${IMAGE_NAME}:${TAG} ${DOCKERFILE_PATH}"
              script {
                powershell "docker build -t windowsservercoreiisremote-ltsc2019:test . --force-rm"
              }           
            }
        }
```

and the jenkins console output is

```
Build Container windowsservercoreiisremote-ltsc2019:ef16889
 C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\jenkins-test-slave\orkspace\windowsservercoreIISRemote-ltsc2019
[Pipeline] script
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] powershell
Sending build context to Docker daemon  64.51kB

Step 1/4 : FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/framework/aspnet:4.8-windowsservercore-ltsc2019
 ---> a82e61390cbd
Step 2/4 : LABEL owner="SkIT" version="1.0" description="����垢蝞∠�IS憟辣��indowsservercore�����"
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 83e11b15dac2
Step 3/4 : RUN powershell Install-WindowsFeature Web-Mgmt-Service; New-ItemProperty -Path HKLM:\software\microsoft\WebManagement\Server -Name EnableRemoteManagement -Value 1 -Force; Set-Service -Name wmsvc -StartupType automatic; net user xxxx xxxx /ADD; net localgroup administrators iisadmin /add;
 ---> Using cache
 ---> db03397c278d
Step 4/4 : EXPOSE 80/tcp 443/tcp 8172/tcp
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 32d9d4a005b5
Successfully built 32d9d4a005b5
Successfully tagged windowsservercoreiisremote-ltsc2019:test
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // script
[Pipeline] }
```

But,when I use jenkins variables in powershell command like:

```
def IMAGE_NAME      = 'windowsservercoreiisremote-ltsc2019'
def TAG             = ''
```

```
stage('Set GITHASH & Tag') {
            steps {
              script {  
                echo 'Set GITHASH & Tag'
                GITHASH = powershell(returnStdout: true, script: 'git rev-parse --short HEAD')
                TAG = powershell(returnStdout: true, script: 'git rev-parse --short HEAD')
              }
            }
        }
        stage('Build Container') {
            steps {
              echo "Build Container ${IMAGE_NAME}:${TAG} ${DOCKERFILE_PATH}"
              script {
                powershell "docker build -t ${IMAGE_NAME}:${TAG} . --force-rm"
              }           
            }
        }
```

The powersehll docker build will fail,and the jenkins console output is

```
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Build Container)
[Pipeline] echo
Build Container windowsservercoreiisremote-ltsc2019:ef16889
 C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\jenkins-test-slave\orkspace\windowsservercoreIISRemote-ltsc2019
[Pipeline] script
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] powershell
powershell.exe : "docker build" requires exactly 1 argument.
雿 C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\jenkins-test-slave\workspace\windowsservercoreIISRemote-ltsc2019@tmp\durable-e5acf825\powershellWrapper.ps1:3 摮��:1
+ & powershell -NoProfile -NonInteractive -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Comm ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: ("docker build" ...tly 1 argument.:String) [], RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError

See 'docker build --help'.

Usage:  docker build [OPTIONS] PATH | URL | -

Build an image from a Dockerfile

. : The term '--force-rm' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check 

the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.

At C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\jenkins-test-slave\workspace\windowsservercoreIISRemote-ltsc2019@tmp\durable-e5acf8

25\powershellScript.ps1:2 char:4

+  . --force-rm

+    ~~~~~~~~~~

    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (--force-rm:String) [], CommandNotFoundException

    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException



[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // script
[Pipeline] }
```

I also try docker build command in jenkins pipeline

```
stage('Build Container') {
            steps {
              echo "Build Container ${IMAGE_NAME}:${TAG} ${DOCKERFILE_PATH}"
              script {
                def buildImage = docker.build("${IMAGE_NAME}:${TAG}","--force-rm")
              }           
            }
        }
```

But it also didn't work,it seem like have some bug when it run on powershell.

Answer (score 0):

The job parameters are available as environment variables to PowerShell - prepend each parameter with `env:` inside a PowerShell script like so:

```
powershell "docker build -t ${env:IMAGE_NAME}:${env:TAG} . --force-rm"
```